# how to use pipe | as part of an sql query in batch script

Tags: sql, batch-file

I am having a table temp (text varchar2(500)). Want to insert this particular type of data in text column : `'inserta('li_count_312'||li_count);'` through batch script.

In my batch script I tried as below

```
SET "p1='inserta(^|^| " 
SET "p2=%var%_%insertat% " 
SET "p3=%p1%''^|^|%p2%^|^| ' ' " 
SET "p4=^|^|%var% "
SET "p5=%p3%%p4% "
SET "p6=%p5%); ' " 
SET TL=%p6%

echo. %TL%

echo INSERT INTO temp VALUES(%TL%); >> temp1.sql`
```

But while executing getting

```
C:\Windows\system32>echo INSERT INTO temp VALUES('inserta(  || '' || li_count_312   || ' '   || li_count  ); ' );  1>>temp1.sql

INSERT INTO temp VALUES('inserta(
```

All the part after pipe is not displaying. I want this data

```
 'inserta('li_count_312'||li_count);'
```

in text column.

Thanks in advance for your help..

Comment: With the quotes exactly like this?

Comment: You need to make sure you escape quotes - if you want a quote inside a string literal you need to use an extra quote to escape the first quote - e.g. `'These are escaped ''quotes''!'`

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that `|` is a special symbol in batch (pipe symbol that connect two processes. [The same goes for a lot of special characters](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php), so you need to be extra careful. As far as I can see, you got that right, though.

Now to insert a single quote in a text column, you need to escape them: `'''inserta('''` will insert `'inserta('` into the column:

The first single quote will start an SQL string. The next two will mean "single quote as part of the string".

So in plain SQL, the desired code will look like this:

```
 '''inserta(''li_count_312''||li_count);'''
```

To get this, duplicate any existing single quote and then wrap the whole thing in single quotes.

In your script, you need to write

```
 SET "p1='''inserta(''^|^| " 
 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use delayed expansion, as then you can define your strings without carets and also the expansion is safe.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET "p1='inserta(|| " 
SET "p2=!var!_!insertat! " 
SET "p3=!p1!''||!p2!|| ' ' " 
SET "p4=||!var! "
SET "p5=!p3!!p4! "
SET "p6=!p5!); ' " 
SET "TL=!p6!"

echo. !TL!

echo INSERT INTO temp VALUES(!TL!); >> temp1.sql`
```

Ot simplify it to

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET "TL=INSERT INTO temp VALUES('inserta('li_count_312'||li_count);'"
```

Comment: INSERT INTO temp VALUES('inserta(|| ''||li_count_312 || ' ' ||li_count  ); ' )
                                                          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00917: missing comma

Comment: Obviously the construct is wrong, but I don't know how your expression should look like. I only try to solve the problem for the batch side.